# I only have UTM coordinates (Excel) that I have to convert into shapefile? Add x,y data doesn't work!

Tags: coordinate-system, convert, utm, xy

I have an Excel file that has UTM easting, northing coordinates. I don't have lat/long.

I guess adding x,y data is only for latitude and longitude? Whenever I tried, it's appearing in different location.

Is there any way to add spatial index to my UTM easting and northing and export that as shapefile?

Comment: You say "Add x,y Data" so i assume, you are using ArcGIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From ArcMap help: *To add a table of x,y coordinates to your map, globe, or scene, the table must contain two fields: one for the x-coordinate and one for the y-coordinate. The values in the fields may represent any coordinate system and units such as latitude and longitude or meters.*

If you have heard UTM does not work, that is because UTM units often stored in one text field with zone, x, and y values. That would require using some other way to create points, such Convert Coordinate Notation.

It sounds like it did work for you if you got locations; you skipped a step in which you tell it you are using UTM and which zone. In ArcMap 10.6 this is done by using the Edit button in the Description/Input Coordinates box. It is not clear what version you are using.